# pointer to __u32 in a header file

Tags: linux, header, linux-kernel

I need to pass a pointer like so

```
extern int Si4709_dev_chan_get(__u32 *);
```

but gcc complaints about missing brackets.

```
Si4709_dev.h:130: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

any ideas on what I can do?

-Earlence

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to include the header that contains the `typedef` for __u32, this is usually `<asm/types.h>` or `<sys/types.h>`.

In anycase they shouldn't be portable, you should rely on something that is more likely to be portable like `uint32_t` which should be standard for C99 conform implementations (and it should be in `stdint.h`.

Comment: Would agree, except perhaps for the part about portability as this looks like it may be linux kernel device driver code where that appears to be a type in common usage, in which case the needed include changes to something such as <linux/types.h>

Comment: This is a Linux kernel convention for a type meant to be shared between kernel and userspace, so it's not supposed to be portable.

Comment: But yes, they are picked up via `<asm/types.h>`

Answer (score 3):

This is an old, probably dead, question, but there seems to be some confusion to what __u32 actually is, but at least in 3.16.1, which is what I'm looking at right now, __u32 is defined in ./include/uapi/asm-generic/int-ll64.h thusly:

```
typedef unsigned int __u32;
```

So, it's simply an unsigned integer.

otherwise, your syntax is wrong, since this is a function definition, you need to name the pointer something to reference it within the function:

```
extern int Si4709_dev_chan_get(__u32 *x);
```

Otherwise, see this for more.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#Pass-by-address_using_pointers